# Mysql passing dynamic content to sql query in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test1();

DELIMITER //

 CREATE PROCEDURE test1( IN contextFilter TEXT )
   BEGIN
   SET @query =  'SELECT profileId AS \'profile\' from sa.topology_network_element' where contextFilter;
   PREPARE stmt_query FROM @query;
      SELECT @query;
        EXECUTE stmt_query;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_query;
   END //

 DELIMITER ;
```

I am trying to pass the object id which i will select in UI as input to this query in place of "contextfilter" , while i am trying to source the stored procedure, I got some exception saying "error in your sql syntax", i am not able to figure out what could be the error

Comment: Change this line ` SET @query =  'SELECT profileId AS \'profile\' from sa.topology_network_element' where contextFilter;` to ` SET @query =  'SELECT profileId AS \'profile\' from sa.topology_network_element\' where contextFilter;`

Answer (score 0):

Remember to be careful with injections of code. Take all possible security measures.

```sql
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test1`//

CREATE PROCEDURE `test1`(IN `contextFilter` TEXT)
BEGIN
  SET @`query` := CONCAT('SELECT `profileId` AS `profile`
                   FROM `sa`.`topology_network_element` WHERE ', `contextFilter`, ';');
  PREPARE `stmt_query` FROM @`query`;
  EXECUTE `stmt_query`;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt_query`;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c736/1)</kbd>

Comment: @user3607869 says: This does not work for me, I am getting exception like this: `Generate report failed :Database read failure:you have an error in your sql syntax;check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near '\'ahhfb66756-jg417823-shgu2977(dynamic context passed)\')))' at line 1`

Comment: @user3607869: Can you provide an example of what you trying to do?